# Как в джанго использовать модели из разных приложений?

Tags: python, django

Всем привет. У меня есть два приложения могу ли я использовать их модели в одной из их вьюх.

Comment: Да, просто импортируйте.

Comment: Не могли бы вы скинуть мне пример, как это сделать?

Comment: Попробуйте: `from app.models import MyModel`, где `app` — имя Вашего приложения, а `MyModel` — необходимая модель.

Comment: Большое спасибо. Если хотите можете закинуть его в ответы, я его отмечу как правильный

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> могу ли я использовать их модели в одной из их вьюх

Да, можете. Просто импортируйте необходимые модели.

***Пример:***

```py
from app.models import MyModel
```

Где:

- `app` — имя Вашего приложения;
- `MyModel` — необходимая модель.